# I get this message during deploy my Rails 4 "Execute deploy:assets:backup_manifest target `<dir>/assets_manifest_backup' is not a directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this message during deploy my Rails4  "Execute deploy:assets:backup_manifest target `/assets_manifest_backup' is not a directory". Any suggestions? Rails4, Capistrano3.0, Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a bug in capistrano. Please open a ticket at capistrano issue tracker.

Comment: to fix your issue you will probably have to alter the clean_expired task of capistrano. see here https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/8e2238d075ffec6a69afdd404e5ed52003e6775e/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/assets.rb#L126

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new in Rails 4 and still don't understand how can I solve this with that file (assets.rb).

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by invalid (Rails 3) manifest files when deploying a Rails 4 / Capistrano 3 application on top of it.

A sure fix is to delete your cached assets folder on the server. In the server, go into the application directory and run:

```
rm -r shared/public/assets
```

On the next deploy, Capistrano will regenerate the assets and continue. Keep in mind though that those assets will become unavailable in the mean time. [This post](http://blog.55minutes.com/2014/03/upgrading-to-rails-4-with-capistrano/) mentions just clearing the manifest file and letting Capistrano re-generate the new manifest in JSON format. That didn't work for me, but removing the entire directory did.

Comment: This worked for me, too, on this similar platform: Rails 4.0, Capistrano 3.4, Ubuntu 14.04. (Also after upgrading from Rails 3.2.) Thanks, @Joost